# How to know how many unread group messages I have

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm designing a database. This is what I have to represent:

- A user can have 0..n friends.
- A user can send 0..n messages to a friend.
- A user can be member of 0..n groups.
- A group can have 1..n members.
- A user can send 0..n messages to a group.

To manage conversations between users, and group I have a table (`Talk`) with these columns:

```
TalkId           (NOT NULL, PK)
Type             (NOT NULL, values: UserTalk or GroupTalk)
StarterUserId    (NOT NULL, the user that has started the talk). 
RecepientUserId: (NULL, the user that has received the first message. NULL if it is a GroupTalk).
DateStarted:     (NOT NULL, when the talk has been started).
GroupId:         (NULL, the group that owns the talk. NULL if it is a UserTalk)
```

I also have a `Message` table to store all the message for each `Talk`. This `Message` table has a column `Read` to indicate that the recipient has read or not the message.

If user 1 sends a message to a user 2, first I check if there is a `Talk` row with:

```
((StarterUserI == 1 and RecepientUserId == 2) OR
 (StarterUserI == 2 and RecepientUserId == 1))
```

If there isn't, I create a new row on it. Then, I insert the message in `Message` table with `Message.TalkId` pointing to the row that I have created.

My problem is that I don't know how to know how many unread message a user has for a group talk.

For a user talk is easy checking if `Message.Read` column is false.

To know if a user has unread messages on a group's talk, I can insert the same message for each group member, changing the recipient. For example:

I have a group, with three members. Member 1 send a message to a group. I have to insert a message to user 2, and the same message to user 3:

[image]

But, this can make grow `Message` table very fast.

I've thought to add new two columns to `Talk` table, the date for the last message sent to that talk, and the id of user that has sent that last message. If I have the date and the ID for the last message in a talk, I can check if there are new messages, but I can't know how many.

I have also a `UserGroup` table to store the users that are members of a group, and the users' groups. I can add a new column to this table to store how many messages a user has for a group talk. Every time another user send a message to that group, I'm going to insert a new row on `Message` table, and increase the value on `UserGroup.Unread` by one. But I think I'm going to mess the design.

**How can I know how many unread message a user has for a Group Talk?**

Comment: Is there any possibility that the client includes the TalkID when sending a message? Looking into the `Talk` table every time might not scale very well.

Comment: And your columns `RecepientUserId` and `GroupId` are mutually exclusive: one of them is always NULL. You could combine them into a single non-nullable column.

Comment: But RecepientUserId is a Foreign Key to User table and GroupId is a Foreign Key to Group table.

Comment: Point taken. On the other hand one could argue that a GroupID can be modeled as a special UserID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a new table `MessageStatus` with the columns `UserID`, `MessageID` and `Read` where you add one row for each recipient of a message (UserTalk or GroupTalk). This avoids the redundancies you would introduce when duplicating rows in the `Message` table.

For convenience you could introduce an INSERT-trigger on `Message` to create the rows in `MessageStatus`.